# Awesome WM: move/resize maximized floating windows

Tags: lua, awesome-wm, maximize-window

In a float-layout, or when having windows floating in any other layout, it is impossible to move/resize them when they're maximized. I would however like to be able to drag/resize them out of the maximized state. This doesn't seem to work:

```
awful.button({ modkey }, 1, 
    function (c) 
        -- I added the if-statement
        if c.maximized then
            c.maximized_horizontal = false
            c.maximized_vertical = false
        end

        awful.mouse.client.move(c)
    end
)
```

Has anyone encountered this or anything similar?

Comment: Could You please specify `Awesome` version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For awesome v3.5.2 this thing works:

```
awful.button({ modkey }, 1, 
    function (c) 
        c.maximized_horizontal = false
        c.maximized_vertical   = false          
        awful.mouse.client.move(c)
    end)
```

Comment: Thanks, works in 3.4.13 as well. Still unclear why mine didn't work though, even though I understand that the `if` check was a bit superfluous.

Comment: Awesome v3.5.2 and earlier has no such property as client.maximized, only separated options for horizontal and vertical. Client.maximized introduced with v3.5.3 release, but I'm not tried this version yet, so no use it in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on awesome 3.5.6, and a similar thing works great for me:

```
awful.button({ modkey }, 1,
    function (c)
         c.maximized_horizontal = false
         c.maximized_vertical   = false
         c.maximized            = false
         c.fullscreen           = false
         awful.mouse.client.move(c)
    end)
```

I'm not sure if putting the maximized_horizontal/vertical rules in addition to maximized is redundant or not, but this combined with `c.fullscreen` works on everything, and it's quite handy =)